# TypeScript error - TS2340 public methods accessible via 'super' keyword

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a long inheritance chain with abstract classes and interfaces in Angular 5.  It's throwing an error `error TS2340: Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.`

The abstract parent class has the method defined as:

```
public get text() {
    return this.el.attr('text/text').replace("\n", "");
}
```

The child class has the method defined as:

```
public get text(): string {
  return super.text;
}
```

How do I get the child class to not throw the TS2340 error?

I've created a stackblitz that demonstrates the problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts2340-super-keywork-public?file=app%2Fnodes.ts

Comment: Simply NOT put the get texts() function in your child class. If a class extends from another the child class has all the functions (method) that the father

Comment: @Eliseo This is true for this piece of code. May be not if child getter differs.

Answer (score 15):

This is a lousy error message, but very important not to ignore it!

My code that led me to this error was as follows:

#### Tracker.ts

```
private _name: string;
public get name(): string { return this._name; }
public set name(name: string) { this._name = name; }
```

#### SubTracker.ts (extends Tracker)

```
super.name = "Simon";   // seems innocuous enough right?
```

And then I got the error:

> error TS2340: Only public and protected methods of the base class are
>   accessible via the 'super' keyword.

Turns out when you do `super.name` you are actually **overwriting the implementation itself on the super class**. So I only succeeded to convert `name` into a global static property. Then **anywhere** I would access `name` I'd get the last value I'd set it to.

---

#### So what's the fix? Change `super` to `this`:

```
this.name = "Simon";
```

So don't ignore this compiler error!

Comment: Just using `this.` doesn't work if you are actually overriding the getter (as in the OP's question), since `this.name` would then point to itself.
You can either use a normal function instead of a getter or change the compile target to ES6 (see @klugjo 's answer)

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, this is not supported by TS and by the looks of it, will never be:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/338

It seems like the only way to make it work at the moment, is to target ES6 in your [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: This is the answer, most of us don't need to target es5 anymore anyways-

Answer (score 3):

As another answer explains, this isn't supported by design for transpiled classes in TypeScript.

A possible solution is to desugar `super.property`, i.e. get a getter function from a descriptor in parent class prototype and apply it to class instance. This can be achieved with `Reflect.get`:

```
class Foo {
    get foo() {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    get foo() {
        return <Foo['foo']>Reflect.get(Foo.prototype, 'foo', this) + 'bar';
    }
}

new Bar().foo === 'foobar';
```