# TSLint ESLint - warn when function accessed as property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint

I have made this mistake a few times - and want to know if there's an ESLint or TSLint rule that would spot it

```
if (this.isBrowser && this.imageURL) {.....}

private isBrowser(): boolean{
    return isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
}
```

Using `this.isBrowser` will always return true, as the fact it's a function is truthy. I either have to use `get isBrowser() {}` or `this.isBrowser()`

Can ESLint or TSLint check and warn that a call to a function is being written as a property accessor?

Comment: It’s not “called as getter”, you’re just accessing a property that happens to be callable. That’s not necessarily an error in JS or TS, so a linter (or the compiler) won’t pick it up; you’d either have to explicitly assign `const isBrowser: boolean = this.isBrowser;` to get a compiler warning or, probably better, validate this with testing rather than linting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Edited, you're right, it wasn't a getter. The linters pick up a lot of things that are not errors (no-trailing-whitespace, no-var-keyword, prefer-const) so I was thinking this might be one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only case when property getters can be handled by linters is when they are potentially no-op, there is TSLint/ESLint [`no-unused-expression` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-expression/):

```
this.isBrowser; // causes linter error
```

This is the case with Chai assertions. In any other case `this.isBrowser` is not a no-op.

`if (this.isBrowser)` is valid piece of code that checks that `isBrowser` member is truthy. It could be valid for a method, `if (this.isBrowser) this.isBrowser()`.

A way to solve this problem with TypeScript is to not be lazy about conditions

```
if (this.isBrowser === true && this.imageURL) {.....}
```

This will result in type error if `isBrowser` is a function.

This is a problem that potentially results from indeterminate code style. If a method that checks if it is a browser is called `isBrowser`, how would boolean property be called then? The fact that a method and a property can be confused and cannot coexist suggests that a a method that returns a boolean may have a distinct name, e.g. `getIsBrowser`, while `isBrowser` is reserved for boolean value.

Comment: Looking at conventions and spotted that Airbnb style guide says not to use getters/setters for a number of reasons (so might take that on board) https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#accessors

Comment: You could have same problem with isBrowser property that has no get/set descirptor. I wouldn't trust everything that Airbnb style guide says. It's biased as any other style guide, and not everything there makes sense at all. Both getter methods and descriptors have their purposes. Another thing is that get/set has problems in TS, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50283765/3731501